# Storing RGB values within a struct c++

Tags: c++, opengl, rgb

so i have a struct named color my main objective is to create a pallet of colors for my program and access them through a single variable rather than the RGB values or three different struct variables.

function declaration

```
WINGDIAPI void APIENTRY glColor3f(GLfloat red,GLfloat green,GLfloat blue);

struct color
{
    GLfloat r;
    GLfloat g;
    GLfloat b;

};
color blue={0.0,0.0,255.0};

glColor3f(blue);
```

I am able to access the values by blue.r, blue.g, blue.b.
But instead i want them to be all in one variable so when I want to access it I can just call on the variable blue.

Comment: just use the variable blue?

Comment: gives me an error "cannot convert 'blue' (type 'main()::color') to type 'const unsigned char*"

Comment: Can you show us the code trying to use the variable 'blue'?

Comment: It's not very useful to define types inside a function, since you can't use them outside of that function.

Comment: well depends where trying to pass it in - with the new edited code - yes you cant do that - you need to use a function that matched the variable type you pass in, or at least has a way of converting to that type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't pass only a **single** variable to [`glColor3f()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd318399) because that function has **three** parameters.

That being said there is a similar function [`glColor3fv()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd318401) that expects an array of three color values. This function only has a **single** parameter, so you only need to pass a single argument to it.

So for use with `glColor3fv()` and similar functions that expect a color *array*, we can actually declare a type like this...

```
using color3f = std::array<GLfloat, 3>;
```

... which could be used like this:

```
color3f blue={0.0,0.0,255.0};
glColor3fv( blue.data() );
```

The call to the `data()` member is necessary to convert [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) into a pointer.

Why am I not just declaring a plain array type like `using color3f = GLfloat[3]` which wouldn't require the call to the `data()` member? Because plain arrays have some shortcomings, for instance you can't simply assign one to another like `blue2 = blue;`.

Answer (score 2):

`glColor3f` does not take your `struct color` type as an argument. So you cannot use `glColor3f(blue)`.

However, you could define an overloaded function like so:

```
void glColor3f(struct color &c) {
  glColor3f(c.r, c.g, c.b);
}
```